# How can I make my discord bot send local images?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm a noob here trying to create a discord bot.

I am trying to learn one thing at a time and I have got stuck on sending a local image with my discord bot. I can send images from the web. But local ones, just no.

The weird thing is I don't get an error message to try to understand what is the problem. After I run my command it takes a while and then it just shows a very long message that begins like this:

```
throw new HTTPError(error.message, error.constructor.name, error.status, request);
              ^

HTTPError [AbortError]: The user aborted a request.
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\Bot\...
```

Shouldn't this simple code do the trick?:

```js
    const { MessageAttachment } = require ("discord.js");
    
    const attachment = new MessageAttachment("test.JPG");
    message.channel.send({files: [attachment] });
```

I have a test.JPG file in the directory of course.

I have followed multiple guides and all of them result in the same delay and then a ton of text in my terminal.

I imagine it is very simple and this is why I can't get over this. Please help!

The long text is the following:

```
D:\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:201
        throw new HTTPError(error.message, error.constructor.name, error.status, request);
              ^

HTTPError [AbortError]: The user aborted a request.
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:201:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (D:\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (D:\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:175:15) {
  code: 500,
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/967690598410760195/messages',
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: [ { id: '0', description: undefined } ],
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: [
      {
        attachment: 'test.JPG',
        name: 'test.JPG',
        file: ReadStream {
          fd: 3,
          path: 'D:\\Bot\\test.JPG',
          flags: 'r',
          mode: 438,
          start: undefined,
          end: Infinity,
          pos: undefined,
          bytesRead: 3211264,
          closed: false,
          _readableState: ReadableState {
            objectMode: false,
            highWaterMark: 65536,
            buffer: [BufferList],
            length: 65536,
            pipes: [],
            flowing: false,
            ended: false,
            endEmitted: false,
            reading: false,
            constructed: true,
            sync: false,
            needReadable: true,
            emittedReadable: false,
            readableListening: false,
            resumeScheduled: false,
            errorEmitted: false,
            emitClose: true,
            autoDestroy: true,
            destroyed: false,
            errored: null,
            closed: false,
            closeEmitted: false,
            defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
            awaitDrainWriters: null,
            multiAwaitDrain: false,
            readingMore: false,
            dataEmitted: true,
            decoder: null,
            encoding: null,
            [Symbol(kPaused)]: true
          },
          _events: [Object: null prototype] { error: [Array], data: [Array] },
          _eventsCount: 2,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          emit: [Function (anonymous)],
          [Symbol(kFs)]: {
            appendFile: [Function: appendFile],
            appendFileSync: [Function: appendFileSync],
            access: [Function: access],
            accessSync: [Function: accessSync],
            chown: [Function: chown],
            chownSync: [Function: chownSync],
            chmod: [Function: chmod],
            chmodSync: [Function: chmodSync],
            close: [Function: close],
            closeSync: [Function: closeSync],
            copyFile: [Function: copyFile],
            copyFileSync: [Function: copyFileSync],
            cp: [Function: cp],
            cpSync: [Function: cpSync],
            createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream],
            createWriteStream: [Function: createWriteStream],
            exists: [Function: exists],
            existsSync: [Function: existsSync],
            fchown: [Function: fchown],
            fchownSync: [Function: fchownSync],
            fchmod: [Function: fchmod],
            fchmodSync: [Function: fchmodSync],
            fdatasync: [Function: fdatasync],
            fdatasyncSync: [Function: fdatasyncSync],
            fstat: [Function: fstat],
            fstatSync: [Function: fstatSync],
            fsync: [Function: fsync],
            fsyncSync: [Function: fsyncSync],
            ftruncate: [Function: ftruncate],
            ftruncateSync: [Function: ftruncateSync],
            futimes: [Function: futimes],
            futimesSync: [Function: futimesSync],
            lchown: [Function: lchown],
            lchownSync: [Function: lchownSync],
            lchmod: undefined,
            lchmodSync: undefined,
            link: [Function: link],
            linkSync: [Function: linkSync],
            lstat: [Function: lstat],
            lstatSync: [Function: lstatSync],
            lutimes: [Function: lutimes],
            lutimesSync: [Function: lutimesSync],
            mkdir: [Function: mkdir],
            mkdirSync: [Function: mkdirSync],
            mkdtemp: [Function: mkdtemp],
            mkdtempSync: [Function: mkdtempSync],
            open: [Function: open],
            openSync: [Function: openSync],
            opendir: [Function: opendir],
            opendirSync: [Function: opendirSync],
            readdir: [Function: readdir],
            readdirSync: [Function: readdirSync],
            read: [Function: read],
            readSync: [Function: readSync],
            readv: [Function: readv],
            readvSync: [Function: readvSync],
            readFile: [Function: readFile],
            readFileSync: [Function: readFileSync],
            readlink: [Function: readlink],
            readlinkSync: [Function: readlinkSync],
            realpath: [Function],
            realpathSync: [Function],
            rename: [Function: rename],
            renameSync: [Function: renameSync],
            rm: [Function: rm],
            rmSync: [Function: rmSync],
            rmdir: [Function: rmdir],
            rmdirSync: [Function: rmdirSync],
            stat: [Function: stat],
            statSync: [Function: statSync],
            symlink: [Function: symlink],
            symlinkSync: [Function: symlinkSync],
            truncate: [Function: truncate],
            truncateSync: [Function: truncateSync],
            unwatchFile: [Function: unwatchFile],
            unlink: [Function: unlink],
            unlinkSync: [Function: unlinkSync],
            utimes: [Function: utimes],
            utimesSync: [Function: utimesSync],
            watch: [Function: watch],
            watchFile: [Function: watchFile],
            writeFile: [Function: writeFile],
            writeFileSync: [Function: writeFileSync],
            write: [Function: write],
            writeSync: [Function: writeSync],
            writev: [Function: writev],
            writevSync: [Function: writevSync],
            Dir: [class Dir],
            Dirent: [class Dirent],
            Stats: [Function: Stats],
            ReadStream: [Getter/Setter],
            WriteStream: [Getter/Setter],
            FileReadStream: [Getter/Setter],
            FileWriteStream: [Getter/Setter],
            _toUnixTimestamp: [Function: toUnixTimestamp],
            F_OK: 0,
            R_OK: 4,
            W_OK: 2,
            X_OK: 1,
            constants: [Object: null prototype],
            promises: [Getter]
          },
          [Symbol(kIsPerformingIO)]: false,
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome!! First... even if the message is long, there is a reason for that, update the post so others can see.  Second, maybe you need to encode the image, maybe the size is bigger than supported or something else that the error will guide better but we can't guess.

Comment: updated the message I am receiving. The file size is 6.6mb so I guess it is fine (<8mb). Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I assume you have read [the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageAttachment) but as you said, url images works fine (as expected from the docs) but local images don't, are you sure the paths are not wrong? Can be subtle but paths for where your image is and where the code is can be different. Other option can be use the "stream" type indicated and test